# How do I know if the $120\rm\:V_{ac}$ is the rms value?

Tags: electric-circuits, conventions, notation

This is one of the questions in one of the books I am reading.

> An incandescent lamp, rated at 100 watts, gives a certain amount of light when placed across the $120\rm\:V_{ac}$ power line. Would the amount of light increase, decrease or remain the same, when the lamp is placed across a $120\rm\:V_{dc}$ power line?

I know that the brightness will remain the same if the 120 Vac power line is referring to the $\rm V_{rms}$, otherwise, the amount of light will increase (since the $\rm V_{rms}$ will then be 84.84V, which is less than the $120\rm\:V_{dc}$). However, I am confused if the $120\rm\:V_{ac}$ power line is already pertaining to the $\rm V_{rms}$. Can anybody explain?

Comment: The way the question is phrased it is almost certainly the rms value.  The question is to reinforce the idea that rms value and the same dc value produce the same power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR By convention, unless explicitly defined otherwise, AC voltages are always specified in terms of their RMS value.

The `230 V, 50 Hz` and `120 V, 60 Hz` standards are given in terms of **voltage RMS value**. Therefore, if the light bulb was connected to 120 V mains (AC) and then switched to 120 V battery (DC), neglecting minor effects due to impedances, the operating power would be the same.

As to why AC voltages are specified in terms of their RMS value - it is **due to the convention**, and this is because RMS value immediately provides information you can work with. I am not saying peak voltage value is not used in analysis, but RMS value is used much more often. Hence, it is more convenient to express AC voltages in terms of their RMS value.

Comment: A standard AC voltmeter is usually calibrated to give an RMS value.

Comment: @R.W.Bird True, but voltmeters can easily output peak values as well. Some actually do.. But RMS value is much more useful information in most applications.

Comment: I'm guessing that a meter reading RMS is assuming that the voltage is sinusoidal. That is not always true. A light dimmer may chop off a part of each half cycle. These are not recommended with fluorescent or LED fixtures which may use a transformer or inductor.  I have a dimmer which uses a diod to pass just half of each cycle. This works with a fluorescent bulb, but doesn't do much dimming.

Comment: @R.W.Bird Modern voltmeters usually measure *true RMS value*, which means they measure "heating potential" of an applied voltage independent of its waveform shape.